# JAX-RS with RESTeasy Factory

Tags: java, jax-rs, factory, resteasy

I am trying to avoid boilerplate code in my client's requests handling through `JAX-RS` and `RESTeasy`. I have several classes, example

```
class User{
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String address;
    private long id;

    //getters and setters
}

class Company{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String location;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I want to have `create()`, `update()`, `delete()`, and `getAll()` responses. For example, For the User I would have the following class with a create method and subsequent update, delete and getAll:

```
@Path ("/user")
public class UserApi {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String Create(@Form User user){

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try{
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.merge(user);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();

            return "{\"success\":false, \"msg\":\"Error occured, please  try later\"}";
        }
        return "{\"success\":true, \"msg\": \"Saved successfully\"}";
    }
```

I would have to repeat the same code for each of the classes I have. Someone had commented on use of a factory class to avoid this, perhaps using generics or an Interface. I have had a hard time figuring it out. Please suggest a good design to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must ask yourself what the differences between all implementations will be.
In this case, not much. You can copy/paste this piece of code, replace @Path("/user") with @Path("/company"), type `User` with `Company` and Bob's your uncle. Em.merge() takes any object, so we don't really care.

So because the @Path annotation is different for all, it would be acceptible to create a new Api like this;

```
@Path("/users")
@Stateless
public class UserApi extends AbstractCrudApi<User> {}
```

All elements that are unique to this REST service are defined. We have our @Path and User which is passed as a Generic Type.

Now we create this AbstractCrudApi abstract class. `abstract`, because we want to implement the common logic for all future services. Interfaces,as you already know, cannot have implemented methods. (Let's just forget about java 8 `default` methods)

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public abstract class AbstractCrudApi<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String create(@Form T entity) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.merge(entity);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            return "{\"success\":false, \"msg\":\"Error occured, please  try later\"}";
        }
        return "{\"success\":true, \"msg\": \"Saved successfully\"}";
    }
}
```

And that is all there is to it.
I don't quite see how a factory can be of any advantage here.

Another tip; try using the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` return type instead of String. This will allow you to set a http response status as well as your response body. You can also try using Jackson to marshall your response objects. Check `resteasy-jackson2-provider`.

Comment: Thanks.. Just one quick question, why do I have to annotate `AbstractCrudApi<T>` with `@Produces`?

Comment: I figured that, by default, all response types would be JSON. So I added it to the `AbstractCrudApi` so you don't need to repeat yourself.